# Request for helping converting odd data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, data-science

I have some data that I've received from a company I work with but have no idea how to approach converting it to a wide data format that I can use for analysis. The data frame is 15,800,000 rows and only 5 variables. The 4th and 5th variables, however, are the name and response to one of the (~90) variables I have to work with. To make things more complicated, the questions were asked more than once, so have multiple responses.

Where there is more than 1 possible response, however, the responses knock over onto the next line (see below).

```
      id       date answer_instance                         pdl_variable_name answer_option
1  25839 2014-02-01               4                      discretspend (25228)            14
2  25839 2014-02-05              11                    legal_services (25495)          [99]
3  25839 2014-12-07               6                     comppen_company (706)          [97]
4  25837 2014-12-15               2               Affluence_V2_P_2014 (34264)             8
5  25837 2015-01-20               5      study_qualification_children (35100)          [98]
6  25837 2015-08-05               4                      overall_debt (27281)          [99]
7  25837 2015-09-03               3                 benefits_received (25465)          [98]
8  25834 2015-09-13               5                     privpen_company (707)          [96]
9  25834 2015-11-12               3            pocket_money_frequency (27076)            10
10 25835 2016-01-18               4               unemployment_status (21922)             6
11 25835 2016-02-05               8                    legal_services (25495)          [99]
12 25822 2016-02-11               3           assets_total_investable (26413)             3
13 25822 2016-03-03               2      disability_benefits_received (25055)          [99]
14 25822 2018-04-01               1               insurance_held_2018 (58085)            [1
15    4]                                                                                   
16 25811 2018-04-13               1                      insurance_held (615)            [1
17     4         11             20]                                                        
18 25811 2018-04-26               2                 profile_work_stat (25617)             5
```

Ideally, I'd like to convert this to a long/wide format that I can use for analysis.

Comment: Look at `library(reshape2)
reshape2::dcast()`. With out a reproducible example, its hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore the format of the data for the multiple answers, you can `dcast` your data like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt.wide <- dcast(
  formula =  date +  answer_instance ~ pdl_variable_name, 
  data = dt, 
  value.var = "answer_option"
)
```

For the multiple options your need to ask for the data in the format that you can read into a `data.frame` if you want to use R.

Having single cell on multiple lines is not the best way to exchange the data. If that is the only way you can ask to wrap values in quotes.

As your file is relatively big I recommend to use `data.table` which has fast `fread` function.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem in data presented by OP seems to be single record spilling over next-line. Hence, once rows are arranged properly it will be pretty easy to convert data in any form for analysis.

Positive look-ahead `^(?=.*])` on `]` and Negative look-ahead `(?!.*\\[)` on `[` has been used to decide if a row is partial and is 2nd part of previous row.

The `space` and `(` has of `pdl_variable_name` column has been changed to `_(` so that it can be read as single column using `read.table`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

# Read from text file linewise
df_line <- data.frame(fileText = readLines("Answer.txt"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


tidy_text <- df_line %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%  # To merge partial row
  mutate(rn = ifelse(grepl("^(?=.*])(?!.*\\[)",df$fileText, perl = TRUE),lag(rn), rn)) %>%  #doesnot contain [ but contains ]
  group_by(rn) %>%
  summarise(fileText = paste0(trimws(fileText), collapse=" ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(fileText = gsub("\\s(\\()", "_\\1", fileText)) %>%
  mutate(fileText = gsub("\\[|]", "\\'", fileText))  # [1 4] is changed to '1 4'


  # Concatenate rows prepared above separated by '\n' so that it read as dataframe 
  tidy_data <- read.table(text = paste0(trimws(tidy_text$fileText), collapse="\n"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #Use cSplit to split answers in multiple columns
  tidy_data  <- tidy_data %>%
    mutate(pdl_variable_name = gsub("_(\\()", " \\1", pdl_variable_name)) %>%
    cSplit("answer_option", sep=" ")
```

**Result:**

```
 tidy_data         
 #       id       date answer_instance                    pdl_variable_name answer_option_1 answer_option_2 answer_option_3 answer_option_4
 # 1: 25839 2014-02-01               4                 discretspend (25228)              14              NA              NA              NA
 # 2: 25839 2014-02-05              11               legal_services (25495)              99              NA              NA              NA
 # 3: 25839 2014-12-07               6                comppen_company (706)              97              NA              NA              NA
 # 4: 25837 2014-12-15               2          Affluence_V2_P_2014 (34264)               8              NA              NA              NA
 # 5: 25837 2015-01-20               5 study_qualification_children (35100)              98              NA              NA              NA
 # 6: 25837 2015-08-05               4                 overall_debt (27281)              99              NA              NA              NA
 # 7: 25837 2015-09-03               3            benefits_received (25465)              98              NA              NA              NA
 # 8: 25834 2015-09-13               5                privpen_company (707)              96              NA              NA              NA
 # 9: 25834 2015-11-12               3       pocket_money_frequency (27076)              10              NA              NA              NA
 # 10: 25835 2016-01-18               4          unemployment_status (21922)               6              NA              NA              NA
 # 11: 25835 2016-02-05               8               legal_services (25495)              99              NA              NA              NA
 # 12: 25822 2016-02-11               3      assets_total_investable (26413)               3              NA              NA              NA
 # 13: 25822 2016-03-03               2 disability_benefits_received (25055)              99              NA              NA              NA
 # 14: 25822 2018-04-01               1          insurance_held_2018 (58085)               1               4              NA              NA
 # 15: 25811 2018-04-13               1                 insurance_held (615)               1               4              11              20
 # 16: 25811 2018-04-26               2            profile_work_stat (25617)               5              NA              NA              NA
```

**Raw data:**

Contents of `answer.txt` as provided by OP:

```
   id       date answer_instance                         pdl_variable_name answer_option
25839 2014-02-01               4                      discretspend (25228)            14
25839 2014-02-05              11                    legal_services (25495)          [99]
25839 2014-12-07               6                     comppen_company (706)          [97]
25837 2014-12-15               2               Affluence_V2_P_2014 (34264)             8
25837 2015-01-20               5      study_qualification_children (35100)          [98]
25837 2015-08-05               4                      overall_debt (27281)          [99]
25837 2015-09-03               3                 benefits_received (25465)          [98]
25834 2015-09-13               5                     privpen_company (707)          [96]
25834 2015-11-12               3            pocket_money_frequency (27076)            10
25835 2016-01-18               4               unemployment_status (21922)             6
25835 2016-02-05               8                    legal_services (25495)          [99]
25822 2016-02-11               3           assets_total_investable (26413)             3
25822 2016-03-03               2      disability_benefits_received (25055)          [99]
25822 2018-04-01               1               insurance_held_2018 (58085)            [1
4]                                                                                   
25811 2018-04-13               1                      insurance_held (615)            [1
4         11             20]                                                        
25811 2018-04-26               2                 profile_work_stat (25617)             5
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

#read file
txt <- read_lines(file = "file_path/test.txt")

#identify continuation of previous row and add it to the previous row
idx <- which(grepl('\\]\\s+$', txt)) 
txt <- gsub("^\\d+\\s+", "", txt)    #remove row number from each row
txt[idx-1] <- paste(txt[idx-1], trimws(txt[idx]))
txt <- txt[-c(1,idx)]

#add a separator ";" to identify different columns in each row
txt <- gsub("(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+(.*)", "\\1;\\2;\\3;\\4;\\5", txt)

#prepare data for analysis
df <- as.data.frame(txt) %>%
  cSplit("txt", sep = ";") %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("id", "date", "answer_instance", "pdl_variable_name", "answer_option")) %>%
  mutate(answer_option = gsub("\\[|\\]|(\\s{2})+", "", answer_option)) %>%
  separate_rows("answer_option", sep=" ")
df
```

**Output is:**

```
      id       date answer_instance                    pdl_variable_name answer_option
1  25839 2014-02-01               4                 discretspend (25228)            14
2  25839 2014-02-05              11               legal_services (25495)            99
3  25839 2014-12-07               6                comppen_company (706)            97
4  25837 2014-12-15               2          Affluence_V2_P_2014 (34264)             8
5  25837 2015-01-20               5 study_qualification_children (35100)            98
6  25837 2015-08-05               4                 overall_debt (27281)            99
7  25837 2015-09-03               3            benefits_received (25465)            98
8  25834 2015-09-13               5                privpen_company (707)            96
9  25834 2015-11-12               3       pocket_money_frequency (27076)            10
10 25835 2016-01-18               4          unemployment_status (21922)             6
11 25835 2016-02-05               8               legal_services (25495)            99
12 25822 2016-02-11               3      assets_total_investable (26413)             3
13 25822 2016-03-03               2 disability_benefits_received (25055)            99
14 25822 2018-04-01               1          insurance_held_2018 (58085)             1
15 25822 2018-04-01               1          insurance_held_2018 (58085)             4
16 25811 2018-04-13               1                 insurance_held (615)             1
17 25811 2018-04-13               1                 insurance_held (615)             4
18 25811 2018-04-13               1                 insurance_held (615)            11
19 25811 2018-04-13               1                 insurance_held (615)            20
20 25811 2018-04-26               2            profile_work_stat (25617)             5
```

**Sample data:**

```
      id       date answer_instance                         pdl_variable_name answer_option
1  25839 2014-02-01               4                      discretspend (25228)            14
2  25839 2014-02-05              11                    legal_services (25495)          [99]
3  25839 2014-12-07               6                     comppen_company (706)          [97]
4  25837 2014-12-15               2               Affluence_V2_P_2014 (34264)             8
5  25837 2015-01-20               5      study_qualification_children (35100)          [98]
6  25837 2015-08-05               4                      overall_debt (27281)          [99]
7  25837 2015-09-03               3                 benefits_received (25465)          [98]
8  25834 2015-09-13               5                     privpen_company (707)          [96]
9  25834 2015-11-12               3            pocket_money_frequency (27076)            10
10 25835 2016-01-18               4               unemployment_status (21922)             6
11 25835 2016-02-05               8                    legal_services (25495)          [99]
12 25822 2016-02-11               3           assets_total_investable (26413)             3
13 25822 2016-03-03               2      disability_benefits_received (25055)          [99]
14 25822 2018-04-01               1               insurance_held_2018 (58085)            [1
15    4]                                                                                   
16 25811 2018-04-13               1                      insurance_held (615)            [1
17     4         11             20]                                                        
18 25811 2018-04-26               2                 profile_work_stat (25617)             5
```

in `test.txt`